# Ionic Won't Work on "My" Windows 7 Environment

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I have been trying to follow the "Getting Started with Ionic" steps and can't seem to get past step 2 "Start a Project".  I am getting the following error, when I try to create the Ionic project.

```
C:\Users\peterstb>ionic start myApp tabs
Creating Ionic app in folder C:\Users\peterstb\myApp based on tabs project

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error fetching: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'conn
ect' }
Error: Unable to initalize app:  { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
```

I do have a proxy that I have to go through, but I had to resolve that to get the cordova and ionic components installed in the first place.  Many of the threads I have seen have pointed to a proxy issue, which makes sense to me, but I can't seem to find anything that addresses "additional" proxy configuration requirements, above and beyond what has been set to accomplish component install tasks.

Answer (score 11):

Ionic doesn't use npm proxy settings. So you have to set PROXY separately for ionic. You can do it by setting an PROXY environment variable in windows manually or via command prompt by [SET](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) (for current session only) or using [SETX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command to set it globally.

```
set PROXY=http://YourProxy:8080/
```

or

```
setx PROXY http://YourProxy:8080/
```

if your proxy requires user name and password you can set it as:

```
set PROXY=http://YourUserName:YourPassword@YourProxy:8080/
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it, at least for login. But when I try to upload, it giveme the same error. Do you know if anything change on proxy to upload the files?

Comment: It also works for me, in this format `set PROXY=http://YourUserName:YourPassword@YourProxy:8080/`